# How to customize Plugins and Themes for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to build a website for a client using WordPress for a school project. The client requires a user system with a log in and storage of user permissions and information.I downloaded a plugin called Simple Membership because it had the best reviews for user membership plugins.

The biggest problem I am experiencing at the moment is the default contact information that comes with the plugin is not the information I wish to store. I need other fields to be stored. I am a developer so I first took a look at the code using FTP and made a few changes just to the registration form to show off to the client for the first iteration.

I have now been made aware that when updating the plugin all of my changes will be overridden. I am here to ask if there is an efficient way to make changes to a plugin without creating a new plugin(does not seem practical, I need to change the function of this plugin not just add to it). At the moment that is the only solution I am aware of. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have to pay for it (not my product), but it sounds like you may want [this addon](https://simple-membership-plugin.com/simple-membership-form-builder-addon/)

Comment: I am aware of the add on but would prefer not pay for functionality that I can easily add if not for updating and losing my changes. This seems like the route we may have to take however.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution but it's practical on your case.Take a backup of your formula plugin and re install it if a new update comes in.

Comment: Im sorry I worded it in a confusing way. I would prefer to not create a new plugin because from what I have read creating a new plugin is good for adding to an existing plugin but I need to delete old functionality and add new functionality. Basically reworking the whole plugin. Would prefer to code it from scratch but my team feels otherwise.